# Is this PHP syntax correct or not?

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans

I am using the following syntax as a convenience, usually when returning a single row from a dB query. My IDE (netbeans) doesnt like it but it works fine. Can anyone tell me if its incorrect and if so if there is a neater way than the obvious alternative I have shown.

```
 function select_row_from_database($id){
        //$pdo is created etc
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($id));
        return $stmt->fetchAll()[0];
 }
```

Alternative notation than netbeans likes:

```
 function select_row_from_database($id){
        //$pdo is created etc
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?');
        $stmt->execute(array($id));
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $result[0]
 }
```

As I am using CodeIgniter I am able to do this with the CI active record (which perhaps demonstrates the convenience better)

```
 function select_row_from_database($id){
        return $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?',array($id))->result_array()[0];
 }
```

Alternative with no nasty red highlight:

```
 function select_row_from_database($id){
        $result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?',array($id))->result_array();
        return $result[0]; 
 }
```

Comment: Function Array dereferencing `return $stmt->fetchAll()[0];` was introduced in PHP 5.4.0 - http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Great thanks! Cleared that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netbeans officially supports 5.4 features.

As shown [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/php_5_4_support_array):

> **Note**: All PHP 5.4 features are available in your projects after setting Project Properties -> Sources -> PHP Version to PHP 5.4 value, or after choosing the same value during a PHP Project creation (in New Project Wizard).

Note that this is available to [NetBeans IDE for PHP 7.3 + only](https://netbeans.org/features/php/).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called array dereferencing and it's new in PHP 5.4 That's probably why netbeans doesn't like it, but it should work if you are using PHP 5.4 or newer. You can read about the new features here http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php